# Printing a Binary Tree using Inorder Traversal

Tags: python, oop, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal

I want to print a Binary Tree using Inorder Traversal, I have these functions and I'm wondering how I would go about writing a function to use them to print the binary tree. Any help massively appreciated.

```
def inorder(self):
    if not self.is_empty():
      for p in self._subtree_inorder(self.root()):
        yield p

  def _subtree_inorder(self, p):
    if self.left(p) is not None:
      for other in self._subtree_inorder(self.left(p)):
        yield other
    yield p
    if self.right(p) is not None:
      for other in self._subtree_inorder(self.right(p)):
        yield other

  def positions(self):
    return self.inorder()
```

Comment: If anyone requires more of the code then I can edit it in, I think this is what is needed though

Comment: "how I would go about writing a function" is very broad: you could write it in a million way. What did _you_ write? What doesn't work?

Comment: @ForceBru yeah I understand that, at the moment I'm unsure of how to go about doing it so haven't tried anything that's even gotten close yet

Comment: where did you get those functions from?

Comment: What is the expected output of the print feature?

Answer (score 0):

Here two possible solutions in Python, given the following binary search tree.

```sh
       20
      /  \
    10    30
         /  \
       35    40
        \
         37
```

#### Recursive traversal

The recursion ends whenever a `node` is null.
Call `inorder_rec()` first for the left subtree, then print the value of the current node, then print it for the right subtree.

#### Traversal using generator

The approach is more or less the same (not surprisingly, as the algorithm is the same). We first need to `yield` all the result from the left subtree, then we yield the value of the current node and last but not least we yield the keys from the right subtree.

#### All together

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.key = key


class Bst:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def insert(self, key):
        self.root = self.insert_rec(self.root, key)

    def insert_rec(self, node, key):
        if node is None:
            return Node(key)
        if key == node.key:
            print(f"Key {key} already present! Ignoring value!")
            return node
        if key <= node.key:
            node.left = self.insert_rec(node.left, key)
        else:
            node.right = self.insert_rec(node.right, key)
        return node

    def inorder(self):
        self.inorder_rec(self.root)

    def inorder_rec(self, node):
        # end of recursion if current node is None
        if node is None:
            return
        # indorder means: left subtree, then own value, then right subtree
        self.inorder_rec(node.left)
        print(node.key)
        self.inorder_rec(node.right)

    def inorder_with_generator(self):
        # yield from inorder_genreator()
        yield from self.inorder_generator(self.root)

    def inorder_generator(self, node):
        # nothing to yield if node is None
        if node is not None:
            for node_data in self.inorder_generator(node.left):
                yield node_data
            yield node.key
            for node_data in self.inorder_generator(node.right):
                yield node_data


tree = Bst()
tree.insert(20)
tree.insert(10)
tree.insert(30)
tree.insert(40)
tree.insert(35)
tree.insert(37)

tree.inorder()
print(list(tree.inorder_with_generator()))
```

Expected output:

```
10
20
30
35
37
40
[10, 20, 30, 35, 37, 40]
```

> To avoid having to provide the `root` node as an argument every time I have added two functions which always start the traversal at the root node without the need to supply any parameters.